# idle_formatwarning_subproc() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)

Tags: python

I have written the below program and getting the below error. I am using python 26

```
import wx

class bucky(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent,id):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Frame&nbsp;aka window', size = (300,200))


if __name__== "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()

    frame = bucky(parent= None, id = -1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python26/frametry", line 10, in <module>
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_core.py", line 90, in __init__
    wxPyDeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\warnings.py", line 29, in _show_warning
    file.write(formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line))
TypeError: idle_formatwarning_subproc() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)
```

Comment: On the [download page of wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php#msw) there is a version for Python 2.6 and an other for Python 2.7. Are you certain you install wxPython-3.0 for Python 2.6 ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using IDLE ?

If so, you might have encountered a known bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue4043

> Actually, it looks like ANY warning will raise this error [TypeError] in IDLE.

In your case, it is a *deprecation warning* that triggered the error. This bug should be fixed in any recent version of IDLE.